# Using LinqToXml to loop through xml

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Experimenting with LinqtoXml to run through some xml;

The xml itself looks like this

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <Owner ContactId="39" Owner="M Mouse" Owed="1,609.39" WeeklyDeductionRate="10.00" FromMinimumReturn="110.00" DeductionRate="0.0150" TotalDeductions="34.14" TotalToBeReturned="1,575.24">
    <Products ProductId="33" Cost="5.00" Quantity="0.40" />
    <Products ProductId="34" Cost="1.80" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="41" Cost="2.30" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="42" Cost="2.25" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="43" Cost="1.60" Quantity="10.50" />
    <Products ProductId="57" Cost="7.00" Quantity="13.30" />
    <Products ProductId="59" Cost="9.63" Quantity="47.00" />
    <Products ProductId="61" Cost="6.23" Quantity="32.60" />
    <Products ProductId="66" Cost="1.00" Quantity="5.60" />
    <Products ProductId="92" Cost="0.50" Quantity="4.80" />
    <Products ProductId="125" Cost="1.00" Quantity="3.80" />
    <Products ProductId="139" Cost="6.50" Quantity="3.90" />
    <Products ProductId="156" Cost="1.50" Quantity="1.70" />
    <Products ProductId="161" Cost="5.80" Quantity="44.20" />
    <Products ProductId="171" Cost="3.88" Quantity="12.00" />
    <Products ProductId="173" Cost="4.55" Quantity="32.50" />
    <Products ProductId="175" Cost="5.00" Quantity="52.90" />
    <Products ProductId="182" Cost="0.50" Quantity="18.50" />
    <Products ProductId="198" Cost="0.50" Quantity="27.40" />
    <Products ProductId="220" Cost="1.50" Quantity="38.60" />
    <Products ProductId="231" Cost="6.00" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="236" Cost="0.85" Quantity="2.10" />
  </Owner>
  <Owner ContactId="42" Owner="F Flintstone" Owed="710.01" WeeklyDeductionRate="10.00" FromMinimumReturn="110.00" DeductionRate="0.0150" TotalDeductions="20.65" TotalToBeReturned="689.35">
    <Products ProductId="32" Cost="6.00" Quantity="0.50" />
    <Products ProductId="33" Cost="5.00" Quantity="2.00" />
    <Products ProductId="34" Cost="1.80" Quantity="7.80" />
    <Products ProductId="57" Cost="7.00" Quantity="3.10" />
    <Products ProductId="59" Cost="10.00" Quantity="16.30" />
    <Products ProductId="61" Cost="6.60" Quantity="13.90" />
    <Products ProductId="131" Cost="0.90" Quantity="1.70" />
    <Products ProductId="156" Cost="1.50" Quantity="1.50" />
    <Products ProductId="161" Cost="5.80" Quantity="17.40" />
    <Products ProductId="164" Cost="1.10" Quantity="3.10" />
    <Products ProductId="171" Cost="3.80" Quantity="5.70" />
```

I have the following code which works to a fashion:

```
 Dim SupplierId As Integer
        Dim lSubTotal As Decimal
        Dim lDeductions As Decimal
        Dim lToBeReturned As Decimal

        Dim lProductId As Integer
        Dim xElem = XElement.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(SubmissionsEditor.Text))
        ' Dim node As XElement

        Dim owners = From owner In xElem.Descendants("Owner")
                     Select owner

        For Each owner In owners
            SupplierId = CInt(owner.Attribute("ContactId").Value)
            lSubTotal = CDec(owner.Attribute("Owed").Value)
            lDeductions = CDec(owner.Attribute("TotalDeductions").Value)
            lToBeReturned = CDec(owner.Attribute("TotalToBeReturned").Value)
            SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(SupplierId), SupplierId)
            SiAuto.Main.LogDecimal(NameOf(lSubTotal), lSubTotal)
            SiAuto.Main.LogDecimal(NameOf(lDeductions), lDeductions)
            SiAuto.Main.LogDecimal(NameOf(lToBeReturned), lToBeReturned)

            SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Process Purchase Order Header Here")

            Dim details = From detail In xElem.Descendants("Products")
                          Where CInt(owner.Attribute("ContactId").Value) = SupplierId
                          Select detail

            For Each detail In details
                lProductId = CInt(detail.Attribute("ProductId").Value)
                SiAuto.Main.LogInt(NameOf(lProductId), lProductId)
            Next
        Next
```

When I examine the log it is apparent that each owner element is being processed, but instead of just logging the ProductId's for each Owner element and then going on to process the next owner its logging all of the productId's for every owner.

I suspect that its this bit that's at fault

```
Dim details = From detail In xElem.Descendants("Products")
                          Where CInt(owner.Attribute("ContactId").Value) = SupplierId
                          Select detail
```

However is it the bit following xElem or the where condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Descendants` method returns all `Products` methods across all child nodes, as documented [here, on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx]). This will include grandchildren.

If you want to include specific product nodes, refine your search:

```
Dim details = From detail In owner.Descendants("Products")
              Where CInt(owner.Attribute("ContactId").Value) = SupplierId
              Select detail
```

Note that I am selecting `owner.Descendants`, not `xElem.Descendants`.